# Troca Texto Leia mais por uma imagem estática - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Pessoal estou com o código

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
function modify_read_more_link() {

  return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>'; 

}
```

Esse Script fica dentro de functions.php no wordpress. porém eu queria mudar o "you read more link text" por uma imagem em png que tenho e centralizar ela.

Como posso fazer? Não quero editar somente o texto quero trocar por uma imagem.

Answer (score 0):

```
return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>'
```

substitui essa linha por:

```
return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '"><img src=minhaimagem.png></a>'
```

Comment: lembrando que este endereço da imagem tem que ser o endereço absoluto, ou seja: ->http://www.server.com.br/diretorio1/dir2/imagem.png

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu fiz a alteração, não apresentou nenhuma falha, porém depois que salvei parou de abrir o site e aparece que ocorreu um erro crítico.

Answer (score -1):

Obrigado pela ajuda, eu fiz a alteração, não apresentou nenhuma falha, porém depois que salvei parou de abrir o site e aparece que ocorreu um erro crítico.